# Network Scanner script returning question marks

Tags: python, linux, scapy

I'm running a python script as a write along for an online course I'm enrolled in but my scripts throw back errors that I suspect may be a problem with my set up rather than the code. I've attached my script and output for reference.

I'm not sure what would be good troubleshooting steps in this situation

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import scapy.all as scapy


def scan(ip):
    arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
    broadcast = scapy.Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
    arp_request_broadcast = broadcast/arp_request
    print(arp_request_broadcast.summary())

scan("10.0.0.1/24")
```

---

```
advenk@advenk:/media/root/Seagate/Tension/Github/Projects# python network_scanner.py
Ether / ARP who has ?? says ??
advenk@advenk:/media/root/Seagate/Tension/Github/Projects# python network_scanner.py
Ether / ARP who has ?? says ??
```

Why are my ARP requests returning question marks instead of IPs?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What's your question?

Comment: Why is my ARP reqiest returning question marks instead of IPs?

Answer (score 0):

### Scapy shows you what it knows

Your ARP requests are returning question marks instead of IPs because you haven't sent them. In the code presented, you are creating the packets and then printing a summary of them. If you want to send them, use one of the [send functions](https://0xbharath.github.io/art-of-packet-crafting-with-scapy/scapy/sending_recieving/index.html) like srp. To see all of the high-level functions you have access to, including ones that send, use `lsc()` in Scapy's prompt.

### Use `arping` instead

To do an ARP scan (which is what you are trying to do), use the Scapy built-in [arping](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.layers.l2.html#scapy.layers.l2.arping) instead. My current local network is `192.168.1.0/24`, so I'm going to use that instead to demonstrate:

```py
>>> arping("192.168.1.0/24")
Begin emission:
**********Finished sending 256 packets.
*
Received 11 packets, got 11 answers, remaining 245 packets
  00:2c:78:20:ee:40 192.168.1.48
  6c:34:ab:42:6b:18 192.168.1.67
  8c:f1:fe:81:36:90 192.168.1.162
  ...

(<ARPing: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:0 Other:11>,
 <Unanswered: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:0 Other:245>)
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you're running your code with a Python3 interpreter. If you run it with a Python2 interpreter, it should work.

Comment: No. The OP code is Python 2/3 compatible, so is Scapy.

Comment: I'm sure it is. However, I think I'm in the same course and when I run it from Python3 I get ??, and when I run it from Python2 I get an IP address.